# Django: permission_required

Tags: django, permissions

I an newbie n Django (3 months)
I have a Django solution with different apps (each app can be access with a link in the nav bar)
I would like to limit access to one of these app to some users: if a user do not have right access, the module link is not available

I was thinking using Django admin permission and permission_required decorator but not sure it will fit my needs

an option would be to have a Profile model link OneToOne to user model with an attribute app_authorization (False/True) and use this attribute in my template nav bar to display link to this app only if user.app_authorization=True
but I sure there is a etter way to do it in Django

Comment: if you wanted to do it in the browser, you could do a custom filter where you take in the user and return true if they have the permission and false otherwise.

Comment: Use the permissions, they are there for that. You can add a custom permission to your model and use the permission_required decorator indeed (and also check for permissions to decide whether or not to display the link). Note that displaying a link or not is not sufficient to block access. You need to also block access for users who will just enter the url manually in the browser.

Comment: thanks for replying; **You need to also block access for users who will just enter the url manually in the browser** -> how can I do that?

Comment: That would be done by verifying the requesting user has permission to view the page in the view/`permission_required` decorator.

Comment: ok but for example, I have this permission: **<Permission: randomization | randomisation | Can view randomisation>]>** and I should use the decorator like this: @permission_required(('randomization.<code_name>') but  what is the code_name of **Can view randomisation**?

Comment: The code name is what you define (if you define a custom permission). If it's one of the four default model permission, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions).